# is it possible to ignore a type error in a casement?

Tags: linux, arguments

Is it possible to make it in a way if i type for example ./test sa   or ./test wn to still have my function echo working?
i tryed with [*a] or [w*] but it doesn't seem to work.

```
until [ -z $1 ] 

  case in "$1" in 

               wa) echo "hi just testing" ;;

  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the case statement is wrong - it's

```
case "$1" in
   wa) echo ""hi just testing" ;;
esac
```

if you're trying to cascade options, then you can use 'or' logic viz.

```
case "$1" in
   wa|sn) echo ""hi just testing" ;;
esac
```

If you're trying to cope with a typo of either character then you can use:

```
case "$1" in
  w?|?a)  echo ""hi just testing" ;;
esac
```

the `?` means match any one character.